# Is there standard ticket data format specification for commercial flight operators?

Tags: commercial-aviation, icao-sarps, iata

I am new to this group and what brings me here is I am doing a research on ticketing solutions for commercial airlines. So I just wanted to find out if there's a international standard specification for data exchange between ticketing solutions and where can I find it *(if it exists)* ?

By specification I am referring to data fields and sizes that should be captured on a ticketing system like PNR, departure/destination, datetime & airport, ticket number & cost, no shows, etc

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! If you don't get a good answer here you might try asking on [travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/). Ticketing and pricing aren't always an aviation issue although they're certainly closely related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IATA does have a standard for [Boarding Pass Bar Codes](https://tinkrmind.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/bcbp-implementation-guide-5th-edition-june-2016.pdf) that outlines a lot of encoding information and other things. This holds so long as [you are not showing up to a Cuban airport in your own plane.](https://mooneyspace.com/topic/20393-201ers-caribbean-adventure-3-cuba/page/5/) There are lots of [numbers and codes](https://www.cntraveler.com/story/what-all-those-numbers-and-letters-on-your-boarding-pass-really-mean) on boarding passes that mean all kinds of things. Ticketing systems may contain even more information than the boarding pass its self and that is up to the implementation of the system. The effective minimum set of identifying information is likely to be (more or less):

- [Departure airport code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_airport_code)
- [Arrival airport code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_airport_code)
- Departure time typically a local time although most aviation things run on Zulu time in practice.
- Seat number
- Flight number (code share possible)
- Date of flight
- Passenger Name
- Record Locator (Some kind of ID for the information)